# Dapper execute stored procedure raises ArgumentException about multi-mapping

Tags: dapper

I have a stored procedure that I'm trying to execute using Dapper that is raising an error that doesn't appear to be pertinent to what I'm trying to do, although I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Here is the signature of the stored procedure that I'm trying to call:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[stp_UpdateInboundDaf]
    @InboundType varchar(255),
    @Id bigint,
    @UserId bigint,
    @DonationID bigint = NULL,
    @StatusId int = NULL,
    @FinalFlag bit = NULL,
    @ValidatedFlag bit = NULL,
    @SignedFlag bit = NULL
AS ...
```

Here's the code that I've written to try to call the procedure:

```
_cnx.Query("stp_UpdateInboundDaf", new
{
    InboundType = parameters.InboundType,
    Id = parameters.Id,
    UserId = parameters.UserId,
    DonationId = parameters.DonationId,
    StatusId = parameters.StatusId,
    FinalFlag = parameters.IsFinal,
    ValidatedFlag = parameters.Validated,
    SignedFlag = parameters.Signed
}, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```

These are the parameters that are being passed in:

[image]

And this is the error I'm getting:

"When using the multi-mapping APIs ensure you set the splitOn param if you have keys other than Id
Parameter name: splitOn"

**UPDATE**

The error is being raised from  the `SqlMapper.GetDynamicSerializer(IDataRecord reader, int startBound, int length, bool returnNullIfFirstMissing)` method. Here's the error location and stack trace:

[image]

Any ideas?

I'm using the current version of Dapper (I *literally* just cloned the repo on Github and pulled SqlMapper.cs into my project just before writing up this question).

Comment: What does the debugger say? You have the source, it should be clear where the error happens. Provide a stacktrace and relevant code around the last traceable stack location.

Comment: Yeah, sorry...I should've included that. I'll update the post with the location the error is being raised from.

Comment: Disable optimization, I suspect the exception is happening on the previous line.

Comment: Ugh...I figured out what my problem was. Updated.

Comment: Glad you found the solution :) Always better to figure it oneself. +1 anyways

Comment: @BobYexley can you post it as answer so we can close the loop.

Comment: Yeah I can do that. I've never been real clear on what the accepted protocol is for stuff like that. So, just add an "answer" with the resolution, and then mark it as the right answer? Feels weird, marking my own answer as the right one.

Comment: @BobYexley correct, just post an answer and edit it out of the question, then accept your answer ... totally fine for cases like this

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I figured out what my problem was here. I was following the examples too literally. My stored procedure doesn't return any values, so `SqlMapper` was trying to serialize something that wasn't there. I changed my code to use `_cnx.Execute(...)` instead of `_cnx.Query(...)` and everything is working fine now.